# Histogram: Bars not stacked, not overlapped, but side by side?

Tags: plotting

I would like to make a histogram with multiple datasets. Then Mathematica allows to either overlap or stack the data from the different data sets. However, I would like to have the bars side by side, but could not find a way how to do this.
To illustrate what I mean:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I want the thing on the right, but Mathematica does the thing on the left.

Thanks!

Obviously I should have supplied the data.
Thanks for the answers so far - I couldn't figure out how to apply these to my data.
Here they are:

```
{{1.25268, 0.944003, 0.508123, 0.835465, 1.08849, 0.730729, 0.539924, 
  0.458693, 0.62392, 1.14587, 0.69167, 0.969927, 0.627031, 0.371587, 
  0.477359, 0.844106, 0.414103, 1.03941, 0.95057, 0.448324, 0.419288, 
  0.362599, 0.482544, 0.129278, 0.39682, 0.838922, 0.870031, 0.566886,
   0.522641, 0.472174, 0.447978, 0.558935, 1.19184, 0.807466, 
  0.621846, 0.765641, 0.701002, 0.998617, 0.536467, 0.602834, 1.04632,
   0.563083, 0.629105, 0.493605, 0.421362, 0.716212, 0.520913, 
  0.653301, 0.688559, 0.612859, 0.21673, 0.683028, 0.381265, 0.638092,
   0.671275, 0.710335, 0.301763, 0.860698, 0.621846, 0.460767, 
  0.716212, 0.719323, 0.642931, 0.665745, 0.628759, 0.383339, 1.0999, 
  0.713446, 0.564466, 0.65261, 0.494988}, {0.698237, 0.699274, 
  0.649499, 0.673349, 0.626339, 0.576218, 0.692707, 0.626339, 0.65261,
   0.63982, 0.544418, 0.535085, 0.67888, 0.660906, 0.675769, 0.676115,
   0.665399, 0.573453, 0.450743, 0.650881, 0.643623, 0.647425, 
  0.64777, 0.645005, 0.643968, 0.69962, 0.62945, 0.55375, 0.670584, 
  0.671621, 0.659523, 0.642586, 0.330107, 0.362254, 0.63982, 0.699274,
   0.680954, 0.668856, 0.638438, 0.703768, 0.690633, 0.610785, 
  0.681991, 0.557898, 0.666091, 0.674732, 0.646388, 0.633253, 0.58486,
   0.690978, 0.605254, 0.716212, 0.659523, 0.619772, 0.672312, 
  0.688213, 0.640857, 0.679226, 0.587625, 0.591773, 0.596613, 
  0.640857, 0.624611, 0.658832, 0.640166, 0.670584, 0.64466, 0.66056, 
  0.646388, 0.528517}, {0.237815, 0.238161, 0.251988, 0.211891, 
  0.222606, 0.197373, 0.220878, 0.193571, 0.248185, 0.226409, 
  0.206015, 0.225026, 0.234013, 0.26132, 0.222952, 0.252333, 0.187003,
   0.243692, 0.211545, 0.273764, 0.193225, 0.236433, 0.238161, 
  0.230211, 0.258209, 0.246803, 0.203941, 0.254062, 0.272382, 
  0.244037, 0.231594, 0.155894, 0.23505, 0.24542, 0.208434, 0.1673, 
  0.230557, 0.248877, 0.176979, 0.218804, 0.213619, 0.272382, 
  0.253025, 0.203249, 0.227791, 0.259246, 0.212582, 0.237124, 
  0.197373, 0.221915, 0.258209, 0.277221, 0.286899, 0.17214, 0.216384,
   0.207397, 0.241618, 0.252333, 0.208434, 0.206706, 0.238852, 
  0.256827, 0.200138, 0.237124, 0.244037, 0.239889, 0.215347, 
  0.215002, 0.119945, 0.196336, 0.196336, 0.208434, 0.247148}}
```

Which with Histogram gives:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edit:**

Assuming the data you provided is called `data` I use

```
Last /@ (HistogramList[#, {0, 1.2, 0.1}] & /@ data) // 
  Transpose // BarChart
```

to get the following:

[image]

You might also want to look into the *bspec* part of the `HistogramList` documentation.

You can also use the `HistogramList` result for labeling/ticks.

```
BarChart[
   Last /@ # // Transpose, 
   ChartLabels -> {#[[1, 1]], None}]
  &@(HistogramList[#, {0, 1.2, 0.1}] & /@ data)
```

[image]

Comment: OK, that looks interesting, but the x-axis is somewhat weird. I try to get this right.

Comment: Yeah, I know. You could probably play around with the `ChartLabels` placement, but the `BarChart` layout does not seem particularly suitable for creating nice looking histograms.

Comment: Great thanks. I have to understand this a little more, but it works. That's most important.

Answer (score 7):

You could use `BarChart` together with `Transpose`.

```
datasets = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {5, 4, 3, 2, 1}, {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}};

BarChart[Transpose[datasets]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Edit:

Using the provided data:

```
datasets = {{1.25268, 0.944003, 0.508123, 0.835465, 1.08849, 0.730729,
0.539924, 0.458693, 0.62392, 1.14587, 0.69167, 0.969927, 0.627031,
0.371587, 0.477359, 0.844106, 0.414103, 1.03941, 0.95057, 
0.448324, 0.419288, 0.362599, 0.482544, 0.129278, 0.39682, 
0.838922, 0.870031, 0.566886, 0.522641, 0.472174, 0.447978, 
0.558935, 1.19184, 0.807466, 0.621846, 0.765641, 0.701002, 
0.998617, 0.536467, 0.602834, 1.04632, 0.563083, 0.629105, 
0.493605, 0.421362, 0.716212, 0.520913, 0.653301, 0.688559, 
0.612859, 0.21673, 0.683028, 0.381265, 0.638092, 0.671275, 
0.710335, 0.301763, 0.860698, 0.621846, 0.460767, 0.716212, 
0.719323, 0.642931, 0.665745, 0.628759, 0.383339, 1.0999, 0.713446,
 0.564466, 0.65261, 0.494988}, {0.698237, 0.699274, 0.649499, 
0.673349, 0.626339, 0.576218, 0.692707, 0.626339, 0.65261, 0.63982,
0.544418, 0.535085, 0.67888, 0.660906, 0.675769, 0.676115, 
0.665399, 0.573453, 0.450743, 0.650881, 0.643623, 0.647425, 
0.64777, 0.645005, 0.643968, 0.69962, 0.62945, 0.55375, 0.670584, 
0.671621, 0.659523, 0.642586, 0.330107, 0.362254, 0.63982, 
0.699274, 0.680954, 0.668856, 0.638438, 0.703768, 0.690633, 
0.610785, 0.681991, 0.557898, 0.666091, 0.674732, 0.646388, 
0.633253, 0.58486, 0.690978, 0.605254, 0.716212, 0.659523, 
0.619772, 0.672312, 0.688213, 0.640857, 0.679226, 0.587625, 
0.591773, 0.596613, 0.640857, 0.624611, 0.658832, 0.640166, 
0.670584, 0.64466, 0.66056, 0.646388, 0.528517}, {0.237815, 
0.238161, 0.251988, 0.211891, 0.222606, 0.197373, 0.220878, 
0.193571, 0.248185, 0.226409, 0.206015, 0.225026, 0.234013, 
0.26132, 0.222952, 0.252333, 0.187003, 0.243692, 0.211545, 
0.273764, 0.193225, 0.236433, 0.238161, 0.230211, 0.258209, 
0.246803, 0.203941, 0.254062, 0.272382, 0.244037, 0.231594, 
0.155894, 0.23505, 0.24542, 0.208434, 0.1673, 0.230557, 0.248877, 
0.176979, 0.218804, 0.213619, 0.272382, 0.253025, 0.203249, 
0.227791, 0.259246, 0.212582, 0.237124, 0.197373, 0.221915, 
0.258209, 0.277221, 0.286899, 0.17214, 0.216384, 0.207397, 
0.241618, 0.252333, 0.208434, 0.206706, 0.238852, 0.256827, 
0.200138, 0.237124, 0.244037, 0.239889, 0.215347, 0.215002, 
 0.119945, 0.196336, 0.196336, 0.208434, 0.247148}};
```

Chosing some bins:

```
bin = HistogramList[Flatten[datasets]][[1]]
```

> {1/10,1/5,3/10,2/5,1/2,3/5,7/10,4/5,9/10,1,11/10,6/5,13/10}

Now using `BinCounts` and `BarChart` together:

```
BarChart[Transpose@(BinCounts[#, {bin}] & /@ datasets), 
 ChartLabels -> {bin, None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Cheers - that's even simpler! - Now this only messes up with the Frame-Options, which I can't assign any more. But I'll figure that out.

Comment: @MockupDungeon There are always more ways to come up with some hand-woven solution :)

Answer (score 2):

This is no problem, just group the data you want beside each other in a list

```
BarChart[{{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {5, 1}}, ChartLabels -> {"A", "B"}]
```

which will give the nice image:

[image]

But if instead you want like your diagram just the labels of the groups you can do the following

```
BarChart[{{1, 2}, {3, 2}, {5, 1}}, ChartLabels -> {{"A", "B"}, None}]
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You might want to allow for the fact that the data range in your lists may not be the same, so that binning might not be consistent. You can accommodate this by extracting the range from the data explicitly.

Create some data:

```
d1 = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {100}];
d2 = RandomInteger[{2, 6}, {100}];
```

Form into a list:

```
data={d1,d2};
```

Extract ranges and plot data in bins of size 1.

```
BinCounts [#, {Min@data, Max@data, 1}] & /@ data // Transpose // BarChart
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see this accounts for the fact that `d2` has no elements of value 1.

Comment: Thanks - that adds quite a simplification to it.

Comment: @MockupDungeon You are welcome :)