# Multiple histograms grouped in a chart

Tags: plotting, distributions, histograms, charts

I have this problem: I have three distributions and the relative histograms. But I would like to create an histogram in which the three columns of each single histogram for the same bin are put together (grouped) by the same x axis value.
There is someone could help me?

Comment: I tried also with BarChart but I wasn't able to put the three columns for each bin side by side.

Comment: Can you explain why the obvious `Histogram[{data1,data2,...}]` is not good?

Comment: It is not my choice unfortunately,but I needed to get the histograms more easily readable.

Comment: It was not clear from your explanation that you wanted to have the bars next to each other instead of on top of each other.  I did not understand the question until you commented on one of the answers.

Comment: Sorry It wasn't easy to exaplain the problem but next time I will try to be more clear.

Comment: closely related/possible duplicate q/a: [Histogram: Bars not stacked, not overlapped, but side by side?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15844/125)

Answer (score 9):

Unlike `BarChart` (with its default `ChartLayout` option setting `Grouped`) `Histogram` does not accept `Grouped` as a `ChartLayout` option value. So, we need to transform the data to get the bin heights and use transformed data in `BarChart`:

```
d1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1/2], 50];
d2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 50];
d3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 1/2], 50]; 

BarChart[Transpose[(HistogramList[#, {-3, 4, 1}, "Count"] & /@ {d1, d2, d3})[[All, 2]]], 
 ChartStyle -> "Rainbow", ChartLabels -> {Range[-3, 4, 1], None}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"d1", "d2", "d3"}]
```

[image]

**Update:** Alternative layouts with the three histograms side-by-side:

```
BarChart[(HistogramList[#, {-3, 4, 1}, "Count"] & /@ {d1, d2, d3})[[All, 2]],
    ChartStyle -> {"Rainbow", None},
    ChartLabels -> {{"d1", "d2", "d3"}, Range[-3, 4, 1]},
    ChartLegends -> {{"d1", "d2", "d3"}, None},
    BarSpacing -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

```
 BarChart[(HistogramList[#, {-3, 4, 1}, "Count"] & /@ {d1, d2,  d3})[[All, 2]],
   ChartStyle -> "Rainbow",
   ChartLabels -> {{"d1", "d2", "d3"}, Range[-3, 4, 1]},
   ChartLegends -> Range[-3, 4, 1],
   BarSpacing -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 (except that I get a different result at +2 and -3)

Comment: This is just what I mean, the only thing I did't need the Transpose command. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You might also be interested in `SmoothHistogram` (new in v8).

```
d1 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1], 500];
d2 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[3, 1], 500];
d3 = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[5, 1], 500];

SmoothHistogram[{d1, d2, d3},
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True,
 PlotLegends -> {"d1", "d2", "d3"},
 Filling -> Axis]
```

[image]