# Histogram two column pairs

Tags: histograms

I am interested in plotting histogram, where in each place I would have two columns, the experimental and the theoretical results. Something that looks like:

[image]

How can I implement this with Mathematica?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen Histogram? BarChart? Have you tried anything? Even it is not straightforward answer we will need a data sample to work with.

Comment: I didn't see the right option in Histogram. Suppose the data is: {1.0,1.1}, {2.0,2.1},{3.0,3.1}. In each pair here, the left number is the theoretical prediction, and the right number is the experimental result. I want each pair to appear like the picture above.

Comment: A histogram needs a whole lot more than 3 data points.  If you really only have 3 data points, then just presenting the 3 data points better represents the data.

Comment: `data = {{1.0, 1.1}, {2.0, 2.1}, {3.0, 3.1}};

BarChart[data, ChartLegends -> {"Predicted", "Actual"}]`

Comment: related/possible duplicate Q/A: [Multiple histograms grouped in a chart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51752/125)

Answer (score 2):

```
data1 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100];
data2 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, 100];
BarChart[{HistogramList[data1][[2]], HistogramList[data2][[2]]},
 ChartStyle -> {Red, Green}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you asked for but maybe useful:

```
PairedBarChart[{16.13, 12.9, 3.23, 29.03, 6.45, 25.81, 0, 0, 6.45},
 {9.03, 73.89, 14.14, 2.7, 0.23, 0, 0, 0, 0},
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"Experimental", "Theoretical"}, Above], None,
    Placed[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, "CenterAxis"]}]
```

[image: Paired bar chart]